# Finite measure divided into small measures

Tags: measure-theory

> Show that if $E$ has finite measure and $\epsilon>0$, then $E$ is the disjoint union of a finite number of measurable sets, each of which has measure at most $\epsilon$.

First, I'm quite confused with the problem statement. If it's true, it means any set $E$ with finite measure is the disjoint union of a finite number of measurable sets, and hence must be measurable. But any set with finite measure might not be measurable, or is it?

Comment: Were you given any more information about $E$?  As it is written now, this is not true - consider the numbers $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, with the discrete $\sigma$-algebra and the counting measure. The set has measure $n<\infty$, but the result isn't true for any $\epsilon\in(0,1)$.

Comment: @nrpeterson I think the question refers to the Lebesgue outer measure.

Comment: $E$ is implicitly assumed to be measurable.

Comment: A measure is a function. A set with finite measure is a point in the domain at which the function is finite. And the domain consists of measurable sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Prove it when $E$ is a $G_\delta$, that is, a countable intersection of open sets.
2. In the general case, prove that there is a $G_\delta$, say $F$, such that $\lambda(F)=\lambda^*(E)$ and $E\subset F$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be such that $1/n<\epsilon/2$. For $z\in\mathbb{Z}$, let $I_z=[z/n,(z+1)/n)$. Then $E=\bigcup_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}E\cap I_z$ and hence $$\mu(E)=\sum_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}\mu(I_z\cap E)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mu(I_n\cap E)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mu(I_{-n-1}\cap E)$$ $$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Big(\mu(I_n\cap E)+\mu(I_{-n-1}\cap E)\Big).$$ Since this series converges, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(I_n\cap E)+\mu(I_{-n-1}\cap E)=0$. So for $N$ large enough,
$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty\Big(\mu(I_n\cap E)+\mu(I_{-n-1}\cap E)\Big)<\epsilon.$$
It follows that you can partition $E$ into the sets $(I_n\cup I_{-n-1})\cap E$ for $n<N$ and $$\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty \Big((I_n\cup I_{-n-1})\cap E\Big).$$